# Shell script - Syntax error: end of file unexpected on Debian 11

Tags: shell

I have an identical file on two systems but one system is running Debian 8 and the other is 11

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          warner
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
to=warning@blabla.com
subject="$1"
from=`hostname`@blabla.com
daemail=$(cat <<!
From: $from
To: $to
Subject: $subject
$2
You might want to check this...
!)

echo "$daemail" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Now on one system (deb8), it works as expected but on the other, I'm getting an error

```
/etc/init.d/warner: 24: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Now when I change the interpter to /bin/bash on the deb11 script, it works. Why the /bin/sh throws this error on newer Debian?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing some changes were made between dash 0.5.7-4 (Debian 8.11) and dash 0.5.11-git+20200708... (Debian 11) that have affected how end tokens and terminating a sub-shell.
Debian symlinks /bin/sh to /bin/dash since before Jessie (Debian 8) I think.

Try adding a LF after the '!' to move the closing ')' to the next line.

I got this from shellcheck.net

```
Line 20:
!)
 ^-- SC1119 (error): Add a linefeed between end token and terminating ')'.
```

Comment: Reference for the ShellCheck error code: https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1119